# Prove the convergence of $ x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \frac{4(f(x_k)-c)}{5k_1} $

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, roots, fixed-point-iteration

We are given that $I=[a,b]$ a compact subinterval of $\mathbb{R}$ and $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function that's differentiable with $0 < k_0 \le f^{'}(x) \le k_1$ on $(a,b)$. Suppose that $f(a) < c< f(b)$ and $x^*$ is a solution of $f(x) = c$. We zero in on this solution using the iteration:

$$  x_{k+1} = x_{k} - \frac{4(f(x_k)-c)}{5k_1}  $$

and letting $e_k = x^* - x_k$ be the error.

We want to show that this error goes to zero and so the iteration converges to the solution.

I noticed that this technique is basically taking the function $f$ and shifting it down by an amount of $c$ which turns the problem into finding a root of $f$ on the given interval. Then this iteration looks almost exactly like Newton's method, with the only difference being that instead of having $\frac{1}{f^{'}(x)}$ in the second term, we have $\frac{4}{5k_1}$. That's about as far as I got in analyzing this problem before getting stuck.

Comment: well the standard way to tackle a problem like this is to use the recursive definition to show monotonicity and boundedness. Have you tried that?

Comment: Try using a fixed point iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have
$e_{k+1}=x^*-x_{k+1}$

$=e_k+\frac{  4(f(x_k)-f(x^*)) }{  5k_1 }$

but

$f(x_k)-f(x^*)=-e_k f'(d)$

with $ d\in (x^*,x_k)$
so

$$e_{k+1}=e_k(1-\frac{4f'(d)   }{  5k_1 })$$

now we use

$k_0\leq f'(d)\leq k_1$

which gives

$-\frac{4}{5}\leq -\frac{4f'(d)}{5k_1}\leq -\frac{4k_0}{5k_1}$

and

$\frac{1}{4}\leq 1-\frac{4f'(d)}{5k_1}\leq
1-\frac{4k_0}{5k_1}<1$
thus

$|e_{k+1}|\leq |e_k| M $  with $M<1$.

so you can conclude using the fact that

$lim_{n \to \infty} M^n=0$.

Comment: That doesn't imply that $e_k \to 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat look now